# Filter dataframe based on letters it contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  Model         A    C
  Neg Exp       3    2
  Power Model   2    1
  Log           2    7
```

I want to perform some equations on these, based on the Model column.

If Model column contains exp, perform A + C
If Model column contains pow, perform A*C
If Model column contains, log, perform A-C

Expected output

```
  Model         A    C   Result
  Neg Exp       3    2     5
  Power Model   2    1     2
  Log           2    7    -5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `contains` and `np.select`

```
import re
c1 = df.Model.str.contains('exp',flags = re.IGNORECASE)
c2 = df.Model.str.contains('pow',flags = re.IGNORECASE)
c3 = df.Model.str.contains('log',flags = re.IGNORECASE)
df['new'] = np.select([c1,c2,c3], [df.eval('A+C'),df.eval('A*C'),df.eval('A-C')])
df
Out[186]: 
        Model  A  C  new
0      NegExp  3  2    5
1  PowerModel  2  1    2
2         Log  2  7   -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `df.apply(..., axis=1)` function, you can handover the whole row to a defined function and calculate the desired output. Even though slightly less elegant as the other solution, I would argue it is more scalable.

```
data = [{"Model":"Neg Exp","A": 3,"C": 2},
  {"Model":"Power Model","A": 2,"C": 1},
  {"Model":"Log","A": 2,"C": 7}]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def conditional_apply(row):
    if row["Model"].lower().find("exp") >= 0:
        return row["A"]+ row["C"]
    elif row["Model"].lower().find("pow") >= 0:
        return row["A"]* row["C"]
    elif row["Model"].lower().find("log") >= 0:
        return row["A"]- row["C"]
    
df["Result"] = df.apply(lambda row: conditional_apply(row), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
df
Out[87]: 
         Model  A  C  Result
0      Neg Exp  3  2       5
1  Power Model  2  1       2
2          Log  2  7      -5
```

**EDIT:**
A little cleanup of `conditional_apply`

```
def conditional_apply(row):
    model, A, C = row["Model"].lower(), row["A"], row["C"]
    if model.find("exp") >= 0:
        return A+ C
    elif model.find("pow") >= 0:
        return A* C
    elif model.find("log") >= 0:
        return A- C
```